# ¿Predecible o predictible?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos

Hace muy poco leí por primera vez la palabra **predictible**. Pensé que era una palabra tomada sin necesidad de la inglesa *predictable*, pero me sorprendió encontrarla en el DLE. Además las palabras tienen el mismo significado:

> [**predecible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TxG7bBr)
>
> 1. adj. Que puede predecirse.
>
> **[predictible](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TxmDg0t)**
>
> 1. adj. Que puede predecirse.

¿Se prefiere alguna palabra sobre la otra? ¿Existe alguna diferencia regional? (En Colombia parece ser más común predecible porque es la única que había oído).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según Google N-Grams, *predictible* se usa mucho más:

[image]
Pero también nos sugiere que es una palabra muy reciente, básicamente solo empleado en la segunda mitad del s. XX.  Por eso, imagino que la forma con *-ct-* habrá venido del inglés (porque el francés emplea *previsible*, la palabra tradicional en castellano).  Y como el grupo *-ct-* es etimológico, se mantuvo sin gran problema (en las otras palabras derivadas de *decir* sufrió modificaciones fonéticas *dicho*<sub>[ ct → ch ]</sub> y *dicción*<sub>[ /tj/ → ci ]</sub>, pero con el sufijo *-ible* no las esperaríamos).

Hoy día, la forma *predicible* —que se justifica perfectamente bien como forma derivada directamente del vocablo moderno *predecir*— mantiene un uso proporcional de alrededor 10% frente a *predictible*.   Pero ambas estas palabras parece quedar sin empleo frente a la palabra tradicional *previsible*:

[image]

Por eso, como estamos hablando de dos palabras nuevas y no precisamente muy comunes, yo no creo que haya problema en usar ni una ni otra, e imagino que si hay diferencia regional, sería difícil encontrarla.  Ambas formas se justifican (algo como *impreso*/*imprimido* o *bonísimo*/*buenísimo*), así que tampoco hay por qué recomendar una u otra.

Sé tradicional, latinista y mayoritarista, o sé moderno, hispanista y minorista, como lo veas ;-)

Comment: En México jamás oí o ví *predictible.*  Supongo que es efecto de la influencia del inglés.

Comment: @guifa, te falló una letra... no es predicible, es predecible, con e, lo cual cambia en algo tu análisis

Comment: "Pero ambas estas palabras parecen quedar" - creí que sería *pero ambas de estas palabras* -- no lo edito por no estar 100%.

Answer (score 3):

Con el mapa de diccionarios, lo predecible aparece en 1992, lo predictible ya es de este milenio. Ahora, en cuanto a la frecuencia de las palabras en el idioma, Google Ngram muestra lo siguiente:

[image: predecible vs predictible]

Una diferencia bastante grande a favor de lo predecible.
Si vamos a la REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA: Banco de datos (CORDE) [en línea]. Corpus diacrónico del español. http://www.rae.es [22/III/2018], aparece 2 veces el término predecible entre 1950 y 2010, mientras que predictible no aparece.
Se muestra una preferencia a lo predecible sobre lo predictible según estas fuentes.